# Ternary statement causing react components to completely disappear briefly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is an example to reproduce: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-kirch-f7fso8?file=/src/App.js

To reproduce:

1. right click and inspect the elements.
2. In your inspector (assuming you have this capability), right click on the `div` with the `wrapper` id and break on subtree modifications.
3. Click toggle button
4. Click "resume script execution" arrow to jump through each subtree modification.

Notice how initially, neither imported component renders, then they pop back in on a subsequent render.

Walking through the example in a bit more detail:

I am conditionally rendering 3 types of thing depending on a single variable using the ternary operator.

1. String - this seems to update immediately
2. Element - this seems to update just after the string does
3. Imported component - both components disappear, then one comes back (after element and string).

Does anyone know what may be causing imported components to briefly disappear? This is causing a flash of content that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I don't think this explains/solves the issue, but generally when you need to update a state variable based on its previous state, you should use the callback form of `setState()` to access the previous value. In this case it would look like `onClick={() => setIfX(prev => !prev)}`/

Comment: I don't have an answer, but tried a few things that are worth mentioning: (1) I thought this might be related to web-pack's dev mode, but the same behavior occurs with an Express hosted production build. (2) The behavior is not related to `import`. It occurs even if the `A` and `B` components are defined in the same file. (3) Wrapping the conditional in a `useMemo()`, and changing the conditional from a ternary to an _if/else_ has no effect on the behavior. (4) React only reports a single render. (5) My only conclusion is that the browser is breaking on virtual DOM changes.

Comment: Having the components in the same file is a great spot. I don't think I fully appreciated that! I don't think the browser is breaking on virtual DOM changes since it's possible to literally see the components not being rendered on the page, which implies to me this a committed DOM change.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `A` and `B` are different components, so on each toggle, you need to unmount the rendered one and mount the other. This means removing the node from the DOM and then inserting the other one.

The other cases are treated as the same element with just a text content change. Not mounting/unmounting happening here.

About the flashing, i cannot reproduce on FF or Chrome. Only if i have the break-on-modifications enabled i see it.

Comment: But shouldn't the un-mounting of `<A>` and re-mounting of `<B>` only occur within the React-managed virtual DOM? I thought that was the entire point of the virtual DOM. That React will collect all of the DOM changes produced by a single state-change, then make a single update (a render) to the real DOM. This is confirmed by adding a 're-render' logging statement to the component. It only logs once for each button click. The behavior of the discrete steps in the debugger suggests that Chrome may be triggering break-points on virtual DOM changes, but I can't find any supporting documentation.

Comment: +1 to what Brian said, my understanding that this unmount and mount shouldn't be committed separately to the actual DOM especially given they occur in the same render pass. My guess is that elements should work similarly to components in that they too are unmounted/mounted. The flash of content is not particularly noticeable in the demo since each imported component is so bare. But unfortunately in my real life use case (especially with animations), it is a bit more noticeable.

Comment: @BrianH. It happens in the v-DOM to identify what needs to change in relation to the actual DOM. So once an element needs to be replaced by another it will have to be removed and the new one added in its place. See here a vanilla JS example that exhibits the same thing when replacing a DOM node.
https://jsfiddle.net/xgk0p9vh/1/ (*enable the break-on-modifications to see the steps*)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I appreciate the additional details, but this still seems to go against what I believed was a fundamental concept to React, which is that React uses its vDOM to batch changes into the fewest number of real-DOM changes possible. For instance, modifying your example: https://jsfiddle.net/0qnLuzcw/ to create multiple in-memory elements before making the DOM swap results in just a single DOM change step in the debugger. React should be doing essentially the same thing: replacing the rendered <A> element with a <B> element in one DOM change, instead of two.

Comment: @BrianH. i believe your example does the same thing. One step to remove the original div, and one step to insert the container div.